# Creating a label from template label in Perforce

Tags: perforce

I'm trying to create a new label by using the p4 commands line, as in, go from template label my_label_template to my_label_1, but I can only find below commands which works create new label from template, but it doesn't seems to have option to input the Revision.

p4 label -o -t my_label_template my_label_1

Is there any way to create new label by using the p4 commands that also included input revision?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a current version of the `p4` CLI binary (2016.1 or newer).

Then use the `--field` global opt to add in the `Revision` field:

```
p4 --field Revision=@whatever label -o -t my_label_template my_label_1 | p4 label -i
```

https://www.perforce.com/blog/vcs/20161-command-line-roundup

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting below:

Perforce client error:
 p4 -h for usage.
 Invalid option: --field.

Comment: @linkback you'll need a newer CLI binary; this feature was added in 2016.1.  Added a note to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, another question, is there a bug on option: -o ? Why I'm asking because I tried this and it do give me the label output without errors, but somehow when I tried to list the new label, it didn't created.  
  
I also tried without option -o which bring me up the edit mode and then save it, it do created successful, but seems not works with -o option?

Comment: You are correct that `-o` only outputs the spec.  If you want to actually create the label, pipe it to `-i`: `p4 label -o (options) | p4 label -i`